# portforwarding a node/postgres application in docker

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, portforwarding

I'm getting started with docker and I am trying to run a node/postgres application.
When I run the app using docker-compose up I get the following output:

```
Starting nodedocker_db_1
Starting nodedocker_myapp_1
Attaching to nodedocker_db_1, nodedocker_myapp_1
db_1     | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2016-08-03 08:33:02 UTC
db_1     | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1     | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1     | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
myapp_1  | npm info it worked if it ends with ok
myapp_1  | npm info using npm@2.15.8
myapp_1  | npm info using node@v4.4.7
myapp_1  | npm info prestart NEXTofferte@0.0.1
myapp_1  | npm info start NEXTofferte@0.0.1
myapp_1  | 
myapp_1  | > NEXTofferte@0.0.1 start /usr/src/app
myapp_1  | > node server.js
myapp_1  | 
myapp_1  | Server running at http://localhost:3000/
```

Okay great, it is working, but I cant reach localhost 3000 from my system.
So I try forwarding it using this:

```
docker build -t devoon/offerteportaal .
docker-compose run -p 49160:3000 -d devoon/offerteportaal
```

The build finishes without errors but the run command gives the error no such service: devoon/offerteportaal

I hope someone here can point me in the right direction.

EDIT:
I went with the second option in the answer and edited my yml file.
I will include it in the question for clarity:
docker-compose.yml

```
db:  
  image: postgres
myapp:  
  build: .
  ports:
    - "49160:3000"
  links:
    - db
  environment:
    - PGHOST=db
    - PGDB=offerteportaal
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/offerteportaal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either want `docker run -p 49160:3000 -d devoon/offerteportaal` or modify your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
db:
  image: ...

myapp:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "49160:3000"
```

and than `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: thanks, I prefer to use docker compose so I changed the yml file as shown in the question.